# Storing values in an array and outputting the highest,lowest,average. Output flaw

Tags: c#

This was a small problem the teacher gave us at school. We were asked to make a program which keeps asking the user to input test scores until he inputs -99 to stop the program. The values are stored in an array and the highest, lowest and average scores are displayed.

The problem I have with my code is that whenever I run it it always gives me a value of 0 for lowest scores even though there are no zeros in the input. Can anyone please point out the mistake in my code?

Code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] za = new int[100];
        scores(za, 0);
    }

 public static void scores(int[] ar, int x)
    {

        Console.Write("Please enter homework score [0 to 100] (-99 to exit): ");
        int a = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
        if (a != -99)
        {
            ar[x] = a;
            x++;
            scores(ar, x);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Homework App");

            int[] arr = new int[x];
            foreach (int l in arr)
            {
                arr[l] = ar[l];
            }

            int lowest = arr[0];
            for (int i = 1; i < arr.Length; i++)
            {
                if (lowest > arr[i]) { lowest = arr[i]; }
            }

            int highest = arr[0];
            for (int j = 1; j < arr.Length; j++)
            {
                if (highest < arr[j]) { highest = arr[j]; }
            }

            double sum = 0;
            double nums = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < arr.Length; k++)
            {
                sum = sum + arr[k];
                nums++;
            }
            double average = sum / nums;

            Console.WriteLine("Highest Score: {0}", highest);
            Console.WriteLine("Lowest Score: {0}", lowest);
            Console.WriteLine("Average Score: {0}", average);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You do not need array for that.You need 3 variables:max,min, currentAverage. You calculate new average like this = ((currentAverage * i) + number) / (i + 1). Where i is number of numbers.

Comment: Using arrays was a requirement.

Comment: You still can store them in array but do not use array for anything later :D. But if you want to use array then just write values to array until you meet the criteria of last number and then iterate through all members of array. Count sum of them and find min/max value in that array and then display it.

Comment: I just tried to do it as you stated and it still works the same. arr.Min() still gives me a 0. I think that one element of the array always has a 0 value in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're copying items, don't use a `foreach` loop and then the element stored in the array as the index that you're inserting to. Instead, use a `for` loop with a counter variable.

You should change this:

```
int[] arr = new int[x];
foreach (int l in arr)
{
    // You're using the wrong value for the index here.
    // l represents the value of the item stored in `arr`, which is `0`
    arr[l] = ar[l]; 
}
```

To this:

```
int[] arr = new int[x];
for (var counter = 0; counter < x; counter++)
{
    arr[counter] = ar[counter];
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you so much. I just replaced this and it worked. Oddly enough this is how I first coded it but for some reason it gave me an error when I ran the code. I asked the professor why this was not working and he advised me to use a foreach loop. Thank you again.